# Find absolutely positioned element's frame of reference

Tags: javascript, dom, css-position

I'm creating an **absolutely positioned element** with Javascript. This element will be used in various different contexts. So **the element in relation to which it is positioned** could be its parent, or any other element including the `body`.

I need to set the element's position (e.g. `left` and `top`) before I place it in the DOM. Is there some way to find out which element my new element will be positioned relative to? I know which element will be its direct parent. But the closest element that has a `position` style that is not `static` — the element my new element will be positioned in — might be a different element.

I considered traveling up the DOM tree and checking each parent element's `position` style, but that seems like a really convoluted way to do it.

So, is there a better way to find out which element is the **reference frame** for my absolutely positioned element's position?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Maybe define a traversing function for this purpose and just use this function each time?

Comment: Why does that seem convoluted? It's exactly how the browser determines the positioning. Just write a recursive function that checks an element's parent until it finds one without position:static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`.offsetParent()`](https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/), which will grab the first positioned parent of the element (I assume in the most efficient way possible). As per the definition of absolute positioning,

> ***absolute***
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any,
>   or otherwise relative to the containing block. Absolutely positioned
>   boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other
>   margins.

It does exactly what you're looking for.

**EDIT:** For a pure JavaScript solution, iterating over every parent is the only way to go. Try:

```
function offsetParent(elem) {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;

    if (window.getComputedStyle(parent).position !== 'static' || parent.tagName === 'BODY') {
        return parent;
    } else {
        return offsetParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted for amazing recursive function. I'm not sure what the quote about offsetParent() is supposed to tell me, though

Comment: The quote is about the `position: absolute;` CSS property, explaining why offsetParent() fits your description. I like to give explanatory answers.

Comment: But why this is the accepted answer? As @n_user defined below in his answer, `offsetParent() ` doesn't work in your case, as it will grab all the elements, not only `absolutely` positioned, which is not the task in the question above. Can you explain, it may be, **@KWeiss**?

Comment: This answer gets the parent the element will be positioned relative to, which could be any element with any position other than static, @Farside. The question does not specify that it has to be an absolute parent.

Comment: @Makaze, what do you say? it's clearly stating about it, in bold in the description, plus in the body of the question: *Find **absolutely positioned** element's frame of reference*.

Comment: I'm not looking for the `position:absolute` element, I'm looking for the element it's positioned in. I've edited the question, since two people misunderstood it.

Comment: @KWeiss, go for it, as you mentioned `absolute` minimum three times, so it was explicit :)

Answer (score 0):

There are methods, but they will require iteration through all the DOM elements, which might not be quick.

Here are possible selection of elements for you in *jQuery*:

```
$('*').filter(function(){
   var position = $(this).css('position');
   return position === 'absolute';
});
```

If you have target selector, and need to figure out if it's nested to any of parent elements, with absolute positioning, you may traverse up among all the parents with parent():

```
// it will return all the parent selectors, with the absolute positioning
$(targetSelector).parents().filter(function() {
    var position = $(this).css('position');
    return position === 'absolute';
});
```

See also [.offsetParent()](https://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/), which might be useful at some degree, but not for your purposes, as you have a bit different task. And here's why:

> `.offsetParent()` method allows us to search through the ancestors of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object wrapped around the closest positioned ancestor. An element is said to be positioned if it has a CSS position attribute of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`.

That means, it will grab the first parent element, which has **any** of those CSS position attributes defined: `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`. As soon as you are in need to filter out only "position:absolute;" it's not working the way you expect, and you need to take the solution I proposed several paragraphs above.